ETL data load DML SP slowness suggestion
We are using Microsoft SQL Azure SQL 2022 (12.0.2000.8). Some of our ETL SPs are running longer time more than 30 minutes. The reason is it is doing a lot of DML - almost 15 (Sometime 100) million Insert, update and delete. Table size is (196113141 rows and size 120 805 792 KB). It is having CDC eanbled.
Here is the sample code: I have tried to match the original code and data, but I could not make it completely and have changed the date to be deleted from 90 days to 0 to test it with current date "DATEADD(DAY, -90, SYSDATETIME())" Also, data which is sampled not going to update statement.
Here is the table and sample insert with 15000000 records, I have tried to load all not null columns.
Test I did with 10 millions for table [TOTAL_RAW] & 1 million for table DLSTYTOTAL. It is working good. It takes more time with 100 millions and log is getting full as well in simple recovery mode.
I believe this needs to done batch by batch . For example 100 millions into 10 times (10 million each time). Can anyone help and share better code.
This table does not have any index and tigers. It has only PK.
use master
drop database [DB_Load_Test]
create database [DB_Load_Test]
go
use [DB_Load_Test]

CREATE TABLE [TOTAL_RAW](
[STYTOTALID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[STYLE] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
[SYTOT1] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYTOT2] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYTOT3] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYTOT4] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYCNT] [decimal](4, 0) NULL,
[SYSHP$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYREC] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYREC$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYFUL] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYFUL$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYMKD] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYMKD$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYDIS] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYDIS$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYSAL] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYSAL$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYONH] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYSHK] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYDMG] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYTRN] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYTRN$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYOPIK] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYINV] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYRANK] [decimal](5, 0) NULL,
[SYCOLR] [decimal](2, 0) NULL,
[SYSIZE] [decimal](2, 0) NULL,
[SYSTLE] [decimal](5, 0) NULL,
[SYSIZS] [decimal](2, 0) NULL,
[InsertedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[UpdatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[IsCurrent] [bit] NULL,
[DELDATTIM] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[DELFLAG] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_C1810429_TOTAL_RAW] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[STYTOTALID] ASC,
[STYLE] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [DLSTYTOTAL](
[STYLE] [decimal](5, 0) NULL,
[SYTOT1] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYTOT2] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYTOT3] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYTOT4] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYCNT] [decimal](4, 0) NULL,
[SYSHP$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYREC] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYREC$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYFUL] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYFUL$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYMKD] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYMKD$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYDIS] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYDIS$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYSAL] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYSAL$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYONH] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYSHK] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYDMG] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYTRN] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYTRN$] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYOPIK] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYINV] [decimal](7, 0) NULL,
[SYRANK] [decimal](5, 0) NULL,
[SYCOLR] [decimal](2, 0) NULL,
[SYSIZE] [decimal](2, 0) NULL,
[SYSTLE] [decimal](5, 0) NULL,
[SYSIZS] [decimal](2, 0) NULL,
[DELDATTIM] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[DELFLAG] [char](1) NULL
)
/*
-- create index

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TOTAL_IsCurrent_InsertedDateTime_inc_STYLE_DELDATTIM_STYTOTALID] ON [TOTAL_RAW]
([IsCurrent],[InsertedDateTime]) include ([STYLE],DELDATTIM,[STYTOTALID]) with (online=on)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TOTAL_STYLE_DELDATTIM]ON [TOTAL_RAW] 
([STYLE],[DELDATTIM])
*/-- select count (*) from [TOTAL_RAW] -- 
-- select count (*) from DLSTYTOTAL -- 

--===== Populate the table.
 INSERT INTO  [TOTAL_RAW] (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) 
 SELECT TOP (15000000)
-- SELECT TOP (196113141)
 STYLE  = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%8)+1
 ,InsertedDateTime    = DATEADD(mi,-ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%(60*24*365*5)),SYSDATETIME())
        
   FROM     sys.all_columns ac1
 CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns ac2
;
 GO

 INSERT INTO  DLSTYTOTAL (STYLE) 
 SELECT TOP (1000000)
-- SELECT TOP (50000000)
 STYLE  = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%8)+1
        
   FROM     sys.all_columns ac1
 CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns ac2
;
 GO

update [TOTAL_RAW] set IsCurrent = 0 where STYTOTALID>500000
 -- select top 10 * from [TOTAL_RAW] where IsCurrent = 0

SP code:
-- Exec [SP_Merge_TOTAL_RAW_DBA]  
go
create PROCEDURE [SP_Merge_TOTAL_RAW_DBA]        
      
--@ID INT,       
--@RunID nvarchar(50), 
--@RAWSPName nvarchar(50)        
AS                 
BEGIN                  

        
BEGIN TRY                      
        
Declare               
@ROWCOUNT  int,         
@UpdatedRowCount  int,          
@InsertedRowCount  int,      
@DeletedRowCount  int,    
@LocalID  int,      
@LocalRunID  nvarchar(50),
@StageCount int,
@DeleteCount int,
@LocalRAWSPName nvarchar(50);
      
--SET @LocalID = @ID;            
--SET @LocalRunID = @RunID;
--SET @LocalRAWSPName = @RAWSPName;

SET @UpdatedRowCount = 0;  
SET @InsertedRowCount = 0; 
SET @DeletedRowCount= 0; 
SET @StageCount = (Select Count(1) FROM [DLSTYTOTAL]);

/*Insert SubAuditLog Started Entry*/ 
--EXEC [SP_SETSubAuditLog] @LocalID,@LocalRunID,@LocalRAWSPName,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Started' 

/*Check Delete Row Count*/ 
SET @DeleteCount = (Select Count(1) FROM [TOTAL_RAW] 
WHERE InsertedDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, -0, SYSDATETIME()) and IsCurrent = 0)

BEGIN TRANSACTION

/*Check For Stage Table Count Then Execute*/IF @StageCount >= 1
BEGIN       
                    
/*INSERT THE RECORDS THAT ARE NEVER EXISTED BEFORE
 ISCURRENT = 1, INSERTEDDATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND UPDATEDDATETIME = NULL*/          
INSERT INTO [TOTAL_RAW] (              
    [STYLE]
    ,[SYTOT1]
    ,[SYTOT2]
    ,[SYTOT3]
    ,[SYTOT4]
    ,[SYCNT]
    ,[SYSHP$]
    ,[SYREC]
    ,[SYREC$]
    ,[SYFUL]
    ,[SYFUL$]
    ,[SYMKD]
    ,[SYMKD$]
    ,[SYDIS]
    ,[SYDIS$]
    ,[SYSAL]
    ,[SYSAL$]
    ,[SYONH]
    ,[SYSHK]
    ,[SYDMG]
    ,[SYTRN]
    ,[SYTRN$]
    ,[SYOPIK]
    ,[SYINV]
    ,[SYRANK]
    ,[SYCOLR]
    ,[SYSIZE]
    ,[SYSTLE]
    ,[SYSIZS]
,[DELDATTIM]
,[DELFLAG]
    ,[InsertedDateTime]  
    ,[IsCurrent]        
 )                    
        
  SELECT         
     STG.[STYLE]
    ,STG.[SYTOT1]
    ,STG.[SYTOT2]
    ,STG.[SYTOT3]
    ,STG.[SYTOT4]
    ,STG.[SYCNT]
    ,STG.[SYSHP$]
    ,STG.[SYREC]
    ,STG.[SYREC$]
    ,STG.[SYFUL]
    ,STG.[SYFUL$]
    ,STG.[SYMKD]
    ,STG.[SYMKD$]
    ,STG.[SYDIS]
    ,STG.[SYDIS$]
    ,STG.[SYSAL]
    ,STG.[SYSAL$]
    ,STG.[SYONH]
    ,STG.[SYSHK]
    ,STG.[SYDMG]
    ,STG.[SYTRN]
    ,STG.[SYTRN$]
    ,STG.[SYOPIK]
    ,STG.[SYINV]
    ,STG.[SYRANK]
    ,STG.[SYCOLR]
    ,STG.[SYSIZE]
    ,STG.[SYSTLE]
    ,STG.[SYSIZS]
,STG.[DELDATTIM]
,STG.[DELFLAG]
    ,DATEADD(MICROSECOND, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), SYSDATETIME())        
   ,1        
  FROM [DLSTYTOTAL] STG Left Join [TOTAL_RAW] TGT  
  on STG.STYLE = TGT.STYLE AND STG.DELDATTIM = TGT.DELDATTIM
  Where TGT.DELDATTIM is null
  
SET @InsertedRowCount= @@RowCount;

/*SET ISCURRENT = 0, UpdatedDateTime TO CURRENTDATE FOR RECORDS THAT ARE NOT ACTIVE BASED ON THE DELDATTIM DESC*/With CTE AS (
SELECT   *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STYLE ORDER BY DELDATTIM desc ) AS ROWNO from [TOTAL_RAW]
WHERE IsCurrent = 1 )
UPDATE CTE
SET ISCURRENT = 0,UpdatedDateTime = SYSDATETIME()   
where ROWNO > 1

SET @UpdatedRowCount= @@RowCount;

END
       
IF @DeleteCount >= 1
BEGIN

/*IF RECORDS ARE OLDER THAN 90 DAYS DELETE FOR RAW TABLE */  
EXEC ('CREATE VIEW [STYTOTAL_VIEW] as SELECT * FROM [TOTAL_RAW] 
WHERE InsertedDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, -0, SYSDATETIME()) and IsCurrent = 0 ')

EXEC ('DELETE FROM  [STYTOTAL_VIEW]')
SET @DeletedRowCount=@@ROWCOUNT ;     

EXEC ('DROP VIEW [STYTOTAL_VIEW]')
    
END

/*COMMIT AND UPDATE IN THE SUBAUDITLOG TABLE*/             
COMMIT      
--EXECUTE [SP_SETSubAuditLog] @LocalID,@LocalRunID,@LocalRAWSPName,@InsertedRowCount,@UpdatedRowCount,@DeletedRowCount,'Completed';      

END TRY               
               
BEGIN CATCH                

/********************************************************                    
 When there is an error, create a record in Audit.ErrorLog                    
 using another stored procedure & passing in parameter values                    
 ********************************************************/                    
                    
 /*Declare any variables that are not already DECLARED above*/                                      
 DECLARE @ProcedureName NVARCHAR(50)                    
 DECLARE @ProcedureDesc NVARCHAR(255)                    
 DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)                    
 DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT                    
 DECLARE @ErrorState INT                    
                    
 /*SET parameters to be passed into the error log stored proc if they are not already SET above*/                    
 SET @ProcedureName = '[SP_Merge_STYTOTAL_RAW]'                    
 SET @ProcedureDesc = 'Merge statement'                    
 SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()                    
 SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()                 
 SET @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()                    
   
 ROLLBACK 
 /*
 EXEC [SP_SETSubAuditErrorLog]                    
  @LocalID,                                
  @ProcedureName,                    
  @ProcedureDesc,                    
  @ErrorMessage,                    
  @ErrorSeverity,                    
  @ErrorState           
*/          
--EXECUTE [SP_SETSubAuditLog] @LocalID,@LocalRunID,@LocalRAWSPName,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Failed' 

RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,@ErrorSeverity,@ErrorState) 

END CATCH;                
                
                
END;

Appreciate your time and effort. Thanks for your help.

The codes seem straightforward. Dont run as a manual query job for 100 millions record and wait 30 minutes to finish also block other users. Change the method. Use scheduled Azure Sql job. Set Top 10 million for select and schedule the job for 1 - 2 hours.

Using batch transactions is a good option, it may not make the process faster, but it can reduce memory usage and log size, and it can also make transactions continuous less time, reducing conflicts with other users.
Since your staging table doesn't have columns that contain sequence and unique column values, it's difficult to split the entire transaction into batches. You must add an Identity or Rowversion column to the staging table and populate the seq value. and create a small table to record the maximum seq value that was successful for the last batch of commited. You can then split the staged data and insert it into the target table. The pseudo code is as follows
--Create a small table to record flag
CREATE TABLE batch_log
(
    id int identity(1, 1),
    execute_time datetime default(GETDATE()),
    flag binary(8),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_batch_log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        id ASC
    )
)
GO

--Add a row version column in staging table
ALTER TABLE staging
ADD COLUMN row_ver rowversion
GO

--Create index on row version column to optimize query
CREATE INDEX IX_staging_row_ver ON staging(row_ver ASC)
GO

--Code inside sp

DECLARE @batch_size int = 100000 --Batch size
DECLARE @flag_last binary(8)     --flag of last successed batch, starting point of current batch
DECLARE @flag_current binary(8)  --ending point of current batch
DECLARE @flag_max binary(8)      --loop bound

SELECT @flag_max = MAX(flag) FROM staging --get loop bound

WHILE (1=1) --start batches
BEGIN
    TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            SELECT top(1) @flag_last = flag FROM batch_log ORDER BY id DESC  --get last flag

            SELECT top(@batch_size) @flag_current = row_ver FROM staging ORDER BY row_ver  --get ending point of current batch

            INSERT INTO target_table (column1)  --insert buss logic
            SELECT column1 FROM staging WHERE row_ver>@flag_last and row_ver<=@flag_current  --get a range of staged data

            INSERT INTO batch_log (flag) values (@flag_current)  --record flag for next batch starting
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        IF @flag_current>=@flag_max THEN BREAK   --out of data, exit loop
    END TRY
    CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        BREAK  --any fail exit loop
    END CATCH
END


Thank you @Rodger Kong. I will check and bring this to my Dev team.
